# PayPal recurring payments PCI compliance

Tags: paypal, recurring, pci-compliance

My goal is to set up recurring payments through PayPal, and getting payment with a PayPal account and a credit card without account; I'm having trouble understanding the second part: what product from PayPal I have to buy/pay (payflow link, payments pro, direct payment etc) in order to not handle the PCI compliance myself? 
In what concerns direct payment I know you have to handle the PCI compliance yourself and I believe is not an option; I've looked into ["PayPal Payments Pro (Payflow Edition)"](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/paypal-payments-pro/) but I don't know if this is what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid PCI compliance altogether you have to used one of the PayPal hosted solutions.  Unfortunately, none of these allow you to process credit cards directly for recurring payments / subscriptions.

For that you'll need Payments Pro with Recurring Billing enabled.  You will be responsible for PCI compliance in that case, however, as long as you're not storing any credit card details in your database then all you need to do is make sure you have a valid SSL running on your site.  That will protect the data during checkout, and again, without any of that data saved on your database there is nothing else you need to worry about.  Even if somebody hacked your system they wouldn't be able to see any sensitive billing data since it's simply not stored there.